# Have SQL Azure listen on alternative port

Tags: azure, port, azure-sql-database

I want to demo something with SQL Azure, but my corporate networks blocks most outbound ports, including 1433. Is there anyway to make SQL Azure listen on port 80?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, you can't change the port Azure SQL Database listens to.